# How can I access the EIN (Employer Identification Number) data?

Tags: data-request, api, data.gov, business, irs

Suppose we need a service that would determine if someone is a Business, be able to verify it from the Company Name and the EIN provided.

Comment: Hi Akhil, Welcome to OpenData SE. Could please provide more details to your question and attribution if possible.

Comment: Similar to this url: https://www.tincheck.com/
Is it possible to get access to EIN data in order to verify if someone is a business.

Comment: Is it possible to get access to this data or apply top get access to this data: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/employer-identification-file